# Expiring keys in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

i am using volatile keys in redis, and i am storing some data with respect to those keys, and i am getting that data from continuous requests, for some requests i have to create a new key and for some of them i have to update, now i want to store the data to DB when a key is expiring, so is there any way to track that whenever a key is expiring i can get some info so that i can store that data to my DB ??

i am using ruby on rails

or someone can suggest any other good method for this kind of task

Answer (score 0):

if you're using something like redis-rails you can pass it a parameter that determines when expiration will occur. Sample redis_store.rb:

```
redis_url = ENV["REDIS_URL"] || "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0/myapp"
Rails.application.config.cache_store = :redis_store, redis_url
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, servers: redis_url, serializer: :hybrid, expires_in: 180.minutes
```